# Gunzip multiple files in folder and continue on error

Tags: linux, gunzip

I am unzipping multiple files in a folder like this:

```
gunzip -f -k *.gz
```

Some of the .gz files are broken which cause the command to abort.

What is a nice way of unzipping all files while ignoring the broken ones?

Comment: Use a shell for loop to unzip one at a time. You didn't mention what shell you're using, so you'll have to figure out the syntax accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this loop as suggested by @Gene

```
for file in *.gz
do
   gunzip -f -k $file
done
```

Comment: This works if you remove the grave accent wrappers around *.gz because using them results in an error as the shell tries to run the filename as a command. Without the grave accents this solution works.

I cannot edit the original answer, because SO requires an edit to change at least 6 characters (wtf??).

Answer (score 2):

The original answer gives an error, because the shell tries to run the gzipped filenames as a command, because of the grave accent ` wrappers around *.gz. But if you remove them - then it works.

I cannot edit the original answer, because SO requires an edit to change at least 6 characters, so here's a new one.

```
for file in *.gz
do
   gunzip -f -k $file
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited the answer. Not sure why I added backticks in the first place :-)